# Overflowing element seems to be causing parent with percentage based width to grow

Tags: html, css

I've got a fixed-layout table with width set to max-content, within a div that is set to overflow scroll, however when the table grows in width beyond the width of the parent of the scrollable parent, then it seems to directly impact the width of the parent, forcing it to grow, when I would expect there to be no change to any overflow scrollable element.

I've got a minimal reproducable here - https://jsfiddle.net/mx9ryn54/

Just make sure the body canvas isn't already scrolling (i.e. make the panel a bit bigger), then add some more `td` into the table row, and you'll see the other elements start shrinking, eventually the body starts overflowing.

What I'd like is that table width to have no impact on any ancestors

Answer (score 0):

Just add `{ main: min-width: 0; /* or overflow value that is different from visible */ }`:

```css
html, body {
  min-width: 1000px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.page {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 220px;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 0; /*  */
}
.table-cont {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: max-content;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

select { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <main>
      <div style="padding: 20px;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <ul>
              <li>List 1</li>
              <li>List 2</li>
              <li>List 3</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
            <div class="table-cont">
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>a</th>
                    <th>b</th>
                    <th>c</th>
                    <th>d</th>
                          <th>a</th>
                    <th>b</th>
                    <th>c</th>
                    <th>d</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```